# Get value from generated input radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

So im generating few input fields and that works.

But i cant get the value of this generated input fields. I can make onchange work, but i still can't catch any value.

So i have tried a bunch of stuff with jQuery but nothing works. I alywas get undified.

```
 jQuery(document).on('change', function (){
        var id = "";
        alert( this.value);
}

jQuery(document).on('change', function (){
        var id = "";
        alert( jQuery(this).attr('id'));
}
```

This is the field that gets generated

```
<input class="mb-1 ml-2" style="transform: scale(1.3);" type="radio" id="input-'+counter+'">'
```

which will look like

```
<input class="mb-1 ml-2" style="transform: scale(1.3);" type="radio" id="input-1">'
```

That works aswell.

But i cant get the id of this input field

Comment: We need to see how you generate the inputs.

Comment: you're missing the selector in the event delegation: `jQuery(document).on('change', 'selector', function (){`

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the element *the listener is attached to* - here, that's the `document`. This fails with your code because the document isn't the one with the `value` or the `id`; you want the *input*.

Take the event argument of the change handler to get to the `target`, the element that the event was dispatched to:

```js
jQuery(document).on('change', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="mb-1 ml-2" style="transform: scale(1.3);" type="radio" id="input-1">'
```